# Why shouldn't one specify FQDN's in some places in BIND config?

Tags: server, dns, hostname, bind

I am currently reading http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/DNS-HOWTO-5.html.
It has two pieces of advice I don't understand yet.

1. First:

   > ```
   > zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" {
   >         type master;
   >         file "pz/127.0.0";
   > };
   > ```
   >
   > Please note the lack of `.' at the end of the domain names in this file.
   >
   > I must stress that in the named.conf file there should not be .'s after the domain names. You have no idea how many times a .' too many or few  have fouled up things and confused the h*ll out of people.

   Why shouldn't one place dot at the end of the FQDN?
2. Author explains search option and gives example:

   > ```
   > search subdomain.your-domain.edu your-domain.edu other-domain.com
   > ```
   >
   > Please note the lack of periods at the end of the domain names. This
   >   is important; please note the lack of periods at the end of the domain
   >   names.

   So what is bad about placing dot at the end of the FQDN, as search options contains FQDN?

**Could you please explain these two comments above?**

I currently see no reasonable logic in them. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about the first part, but a) I can't find 2 in the link, and b) 2 seems to be about `resolv.conf`, in which case you shouldn't have `.` after the search domains because those domains are appended to the name you are resolving (so `nslookup foo` would look up `foo.subdomain.your-domain.edu`, `foo.your-domain.edu`, etc.). Clearly that won't work if you have a `.` at the end of those search domains.

Comment: 1. Edited the question.
2. Indeed why it doesn't work? Isn't the nslookup foo.subdomain.your-domain.edu. (Note the trailing dot) Is valid query? I always thought that we pass FQDN to dig/host/nslookup. I tested with "search my.zone." and it works. You could write an answer if you please.

Comment: Look [here at FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name#Syntax) in the wiki, and read the section for Syntax.  It explains the period (.).

Comment: It works, but that says you're specifying a FQDN - and nothing more should be appended - however, depending on your setup, something downstream *may* need to append things to it - and that could break.

Comment: @muru, could you please elaborate more on "something downstream may need to append". I thought that resolver takes name, appends search domains in round-robin fashion and passes them unchanged to one of the DNS servers, which don't append anything to them but treat queries unaltered. Correct me, please.

Comment: @Terrance, It contains general information, it says nothing why shouldn't one add period at at the end of search domains in resolv.conf , that is partially what my question is all about.

Comment: @BulatM. not necessarily - the DNS server (?) may have its own settings for appending search domain. IIRC some of my routers had a DNS caching service, which accepted search domains, so I wouldn't need to specify them in my `resolv.conf`. Similar configs might exist for other reasons.

Comment: @muru, just to be sure: you mean that if one adds dot-ended search domain in resolv.conf, then resolver appends search domain with period at the end, the DNS sees FQDN in the query and could not append more his custom search domains thus causing problem(getting FQDN too early with no possibility to append more). You could write an excellent answer comprising all of these pieces of knowledge to coherent.

Comment: @muru, I would be glad you if share your opinion on first part of the question too.